# Is there a detectable difference between a scheduled unpublish and unpublishing directly?

Tags: 2011, publishing, event-system

I'd like to distinguish between a scheduled unpublish action and an immediate unpublish action via the Event System. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `UnPublishEventArgs` there is a member `UnPublishInstruction`.
This will have a property - `StartAt` - If StartAt property is set to DateTime.MinValue that means the Unpublishing is scheduled for Immediate unpublish and if it is set to a particular datetime, that means it is schedule to unpublish at some other time.

Comment: Realized after submit that a similar answer has already been submitted :P

Answer (score 6):

Of course. `UnPublishEventArgs` has property `UnPublishInstruction` which in turn has `StartAt`. So if `StartAt` is set - it's scheduled action

Comment: One small correction - the StartAt will always be set to some value - If it is set to DateTime.MinValue then the unpublishing is immediate and if it set to any other particular datetime, then it is schedule for some later time :)